# Postgres Query for Getting Records between two dates with added conditional

Tags: typescript, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

This feels like it's been answered before but nothing I am trying is working. I have a table that has an account, a balance, and a timestamp. I want to select all records (including balances) for an account between two timestamps. I've tried the BETWEEN operator with the AND, I've tried >= and <= but I keep getting 0 rows when I know there are additional rows in there. It seems to work when I only add in 1 conditional for >= or <= separately, but when combined rows come back empty.

I'm using Typescript and passing in Dates into there using `pg` and a little bit of middleware. I am using a conditional that if the transactionsAfter and transactionsBefore are not defined that they should be set to `new Date(0)` and `new Date()` (aka now) respectively.

```
        if (transactionsAfter === undefined) {
            transactionsAfter = new Date(0);
        }

        if (transactionsBefore === undefined) {
            transactionsBefore = new Date();
        }
        
                const creditsAndDebitsWrap = await transaction.client.query<{
            account: string,
            currency: string,
            amount: string,
            timestamp: string,
            uuid: string
        }>(
            'SELECT * FROM creditsAndDebits WHERE account = $1 AND timestamp >= $2 AND timestamp <= $3 ORDER BY timestamp DESC',
            [
                accountPubKey,
                transactionsAfter,
                transactionsBefore
            ]);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS creditsAndDebits(account TEXT NOT NULL, currency TEXT, amount TEXT NOT NULL, timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, uuid TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(account, currency, uuid))
```

I've tried this:

```
'SELECT * FROM creditsAndDebits WHERE account = $1 AND timestamp >= $2::timestamp AND timestamp <= $3::timestamp ORDER BY timestamp DESC',
            [
                accountPubKey,
                transactionsAfter,
                transactionsBefore
            ]);
```

and this:

```
'SELECT * FROM creditsAndDebits WHERE account = $1 AND timestamp BETWEEN $2::timestamp AND $3::timestamp ORDER BY timestamp DESC',
            [
                accountPubKey,
                transactionsAfter,
                transactionsBefore
            ]);
```

Someone please point out that I've been doing something dumb the entire time.

Comment: What language / library / runtime / etc are you using to execute these queries? What are the data types and values for `transactionsAfter` and `transactionsBefore`?

Comment: Let me add that in.

Comment: "I want to select all records"  Well, since account is a primary key, how could that be plural?

Comment: I took it out for the example sake but the primary key is actually a compound primary key with other records to ensure uniqueness

Comment: Added in some examples for what the compound primary key represents

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! So the problem was that Date in typescript is not timestamp compliant for PostgreSQL, so what I needed to do was to pass transactionsAfter and transactionsBefore as ISO strings using `.toISOString()` on each date value. The query worked like a charm after that.